# How do I push a group of values to an array with Javascript push()?

Tags: javascript, json, function

Can anybody spot the error here? Checkpoint 1 triggers but not checkpoint 2. Can't figure out what's wrong with my statement.

```
    <script>
        function shoppingCart() {

            var item,
                price,
                qty,
                items = {
                    itemID: "B17",
                    itemPrice: 17,
                    itemQty: 1
                    };

        function addItem(item, price, qty) {
             alert("checkpoint 1");
               items.push({
               itemID: item,                  
               itemPrice: price,
               itemQty: qty
               });
             alert("checkpoint 2");

        };

};
        cart = new shoppingCart();

        cart.addItem("b4",14,1);
        alert(cart.items.itemID);
    </script>
```

Comment: **This question appears to be off-topic because the item is not an array, and OP showed no sign of self research**

Comment: Pretty quick on the down vote there, Pal, for a guy who has nothing constructive to offer. I spent hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. From what I was finding on the web, an array IS an object in JS, and the distinction was a little nebulous for a novice such as myself.

Comment: Everything is an object in javascript, you wouldn't use `push()` on a string would you? This site isn't a debugging tool. Your browsers console is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = {
    itemID: "B17",
    itemPrice: 17,
    itemQty: 1
};
```

is not an array.  It should be:

```
items =[{
    itemID: "B17",
    itemPrice: 17,
    itemQty: 1
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that items is not an array, but an object. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pCc9w/

all code, fixed:

```
        function shoppingCart() {

            var item,
                price,
                qty;
                this.items = [{
                    itemID: "B17",
                    itemPrice: 17,
                    itemQty: 1
                    }];



};

       shoppingCart.prototype.addItem = function(item, price, qty) {
             alert("checkpoint 1");
               this.items.push({
               itemID: item,                  
               itemPrice: price,
               itemQty: qty
               });
             alert("checkpoint 2");

        };
        cart = new shoppingCart();

        cart.addItem("b4",14,1);
        alert(cart.items[1].itemID);
```

Comment: Maybe make addItem in the prototype?

Comment: @ZekeAlexandreNierenberg You're right, edited and added prototype.